# How can I delete a row after a time

Tags: sql, spring-boot, mariadb

I have a process that creates a row in a SQL table with date and time.

After creating this row, I need to remove it after 3 months.

How can I do this in SQL or in my SpringBoot code?

Comment: Php My Admin : Maria DB

Answer (score 0):

you can create an event and schedule it to do it for automatically :

```
CREATE EVENT test_event 
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 Day DO 
   DELETE FROM yourtable t
   WHERE t.datecolumn < current_date - interval 3 month;
```